# Regex for capturing a text in two double quotes

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to get a regex that will find `text1` and `text2` into the examples below :

```
,"blabla "test1" blabla", "another text"

,"blabla "test2" blabla", "another text"
```

To summarize, I want all text that are between double quotes, and inside a text between double quote and coma.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This expression would likely do that:

```
 ".+?"(.+?)".+?"
```

and our desired outputs are in this capturing group:

```
 (.+?)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3fGr0C/1/)

```js
const regex = /".+?"(.+?)".+?"/gm;
const str = `,"blabla "test1" blabla", "another text"
,"blabla "test2" blabla", "another text"`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```